# RecylerView not updating new data unless the emulator is refreshed by turning on and off

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**Context:** Need to build an android application(for uni) that parses XML data from an Rss feed for traffic data. I am getting data no issues. But I was trying to implement a spinner than when its changed, it will fetch the new data from another API link. The data is getting grabbed fine.

**Problem:** The view isn't being updated unless I press the emulator device (Off/On) then the new data is shown properly.

**Tried Solution**:
I have tried using mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong.
PS(Really new to Java/Android Studio). **Any suggestions why its only updating once I refresh the device either by turning the phone on and off.**

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST =9001;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ItemRecycleAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private EditText search;
private String urlSource = "https://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/roadworks.aspx";
private HandleXml obj;
private ListView listView;
private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
private SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
private String current_date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
private DatePicker datePicker;
private Button sbmt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.feedType);
    search = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.inputDate);
    search.setText(current_date);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recView);
    obj = new HandleXml(this.urlSource);
    try {
        mAdapter = new ItemRecycleAdapter(obj.fetchXml());

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.feedValues, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    if(isMapOK()){
        Log.i("fine", "MAP IS OKAY");
        init();
    }
}
```

**ItemRecycleAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecycleAdapter.ItemRecyleHolder> implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<Item> mArrayList;
private ArrayList<Item> mArrayListCopy;

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return itemFilter;
}

public static class ItemRecyleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;
    public TextView desc;
    public TextView pubDate;

    public ItemRecyleHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc =itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        pubDate =itemView.findViewById(R.id.pubDate);
    }
}
public ItemRecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Item> itemList){
    this.mArrayList = itemList;
    this.mArrayListCopy =  itemList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void set_data(ArrayList<Item>newList){
    if(mArrayList != null){
        mArrayList.clear();
        mArrayList = newList;
    }else{
        mArrayList = newList;
    }
   // notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void updateData(ArrayList<Item> newList){
    this.mArrayList.clear();
    this.mArrayList = newList;
    //notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemRecyleHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_view_layout, parent, false);
    ItemRecyleHolder irh = new ItemRecyleHolder(v);
    return irh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemRecyleHolder holder, int position) {
    Item currentItem = mArrayList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    holder.pubDate.setText(sdf.format(currentItem.getPublishDate()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}
```

**onItemSelected (testing with one option in the spinner, in MainActivity)**

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    //this.urlSource = text;
    if(text.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("roadworks")){
        this.urlSource = "https://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/roadworks.aspx";
        //Log.i("Url", "Url changed" + this.urlSource);
    }else if(text.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("Planned Roadworks")){
        this.urlSource = "https://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/plannedroadworks.aspx";
        ArrayList<Item> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            obj = new HandleXml(this.urlSource);
            newList = obj.fetchXml();
            mAdapter.set_data(newList);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        this.urlSource = "https://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/currentincidents.aspx";
        Log.i("Url", "Url changed" + this.urlSource);
    }

}
```

Comment: as you're changing all the data of your adapter , then try assigning new adapter with new data to old adapter reference then set that adapter to database, and can you also tell me do you have something in the onStop() method, or onPause() method

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I'm not using any database, nor have a onStop() or onPause() method.

Cheers

Comment: then you can try setting new adapter to your recyclerview , because you're changing all the data of the adapter, that way your code will become simpler , you can get rid off set_data method, you can also follow good practices like using methods , and naming methods as java naming conventions to make your code more readable

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I tried setting a new adapter but the same issue, its not refreshing immedietly, is there any chance you could provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

In onItemSelected try this

```
obj = new HandleXml(this.urlSource);
       mAdapter = null;
    try {
       mAdapter = new ItemRecycleAdapter(obj.fetchXml());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(mAdapter ! = null)
    mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

Comment: Still the same result, I have to turn the emulator device off and then on to view the new data, appreciate you trying to help tho.

Comment: turn off means , lock it by the side button, and after waking you get expected result right?

Comment: Correct yeah! Apologies.